# How to make a responsive row with 3 cards in it with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a 3 cards but when i put all three of them in a row its appears two cards and the other card under it... i want to put all three of them in one row and also i want it be responsive with other devices.
i want it to show like the cards in this website( i don't mean the same shape, i mean in one row and responsive):
https://linksfire.co/
this is my code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-4 card">1</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4 card">2</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4 card">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you show us the important part of the code? So we can help you precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card">1</div>
        <div class="col card">2</div>
        <div class="col card">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card">4</div>
        <div class="col card">5</div>
        <div class="col card">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card">1</div>
        <div class="col card">2</div>
        <div class="col card">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card">4</div>
        <div class="col card">5</div>
        <div class="col card">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to do that but i want it to be responsive with other devices.....the problem is when i write "col-md-4"in every div class it making a row but two divs are above and one is under it

Comment: My example does what is described in the question. If a problem arises or if a different behavior of cards on different devices is required, describe it in the question or provide the code. 

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 3):

Use `col-4` should you need to have 3 columns irrespective of viewport width.

`.card` has `1px` border by default. You have 3 cards and  the total size of the border-x of them is `6px`. It might be the reason that your layout breaks. So you should use `.card`  on a seperate element.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="card">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="card">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="card">1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```